# well formed XML DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I ran my XML/DTD through w3schools validator it tells me it has allot of errors, what am I doing wrong? I will admit it's been a few years since I used XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE WEBDESIGNTOPICS [
<!ELEMENT WEBDESIGNTOPICS (topic+,topicname+,description+,provided)>
<!ELEMENT topic (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT topicname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT provided (#PCDATA)>
]>
<WEBDESIGNTOPICS>
<topic>
    <topicname>HTML5</topicname>
    <description>HAMILTON</description>
    <provided>SALESMAN</provided>

</topic>
<topic>
    <topicname>CSS/CSS3</topicname>
    <description>SMITH</description>
    <provided>CLEANER</provided>

</topic>
<topic>
    <topicname>PHP</topicname>
    <description>JONES</description>
    <provided>MANAGER</provided>
</topic>
<topic>
    <topicname>JavaScript</topicname>
    <description>JONES</description>
    <provided>MANAGER</provided>
</topic>
<topic>
    <topicname>jQuery</topicname>
    <description>JONES</description>
    <provided>MANAGER</provided>
</topic>
</WEBDESIGNTOPICS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your XML document is ***well-formed*** but is not ***valid***.  You can read about [**the difference between *well-formed* and *invalid* here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

**To make your XML be valid:**

1. Change the content model of `WEBDESIGNTOPICS` to reflect the fact
   that it's clearly just a list of `topics`:

   ```
    <!ELEMENT WEBDESIGNTOPICS (topic+)>
   ```
2. Change the content model of topic to reflect that it can consist of
   a `topicname`, `description`, and `provided` element or elements. 
   You have to decide on the requiredness and cardinality as the sample
   XML cannot indicate generality itself:

   ```
   <!ELEMENT topic (topicname,description,provided)>
   ```

**Altogether then, this updated XML document will be valid:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE WEBDESIGNTOPICS [
<!ELEMENT WEBDESIGNTOPICS (topic+)>
<!ELEMENT topic (topicname,description,provided)>
<!ELEMENT topicname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT provided (#PCDATA)>
]>
<WEBDESIGNTOPICS>
    <topic>
        <topicname>HTML5</topicname>
        <description>HAMILTON</description>
        <provided>SALESMAN</provided>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <topicname>CSS/CSS3</topicname>
        <description>SMITH</description>
        <provided>CLEANER</provided>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <topicname>PHP</topicname>
        <description>JONES</description>
        <provided>MANAGER</provided>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <topicname>JavaScript</topicname>
        <description>JONES</description>
        <provided>MANAGER</provided>
    </topic>
    <topic>
        <topicname>jQuery</topicname>
        <description>JONES</description>
        <provided>MANAGER</provided>
    </topic>
</WEBDESIGNTOPICS>
```